logback.xmlで出力しているファイルがフォルダ移動できない
logback.xmlを使用しているjavaアプリケーションにて、以下のルールでログを出力をしています。
・アプリ起動時に0byteのログファイルを作成。
・最大ファイル容量超えor日付が変わったタイミングでローテーションする。
　　例）起動直後：log_20240409-0.log
　　　　ローテーション後：log_20240409-0.log、log_20240409-1.log、log_20240409-2.log
上記ローテーション後の例の場合、アプリが書き込む対象のファイルは「log_20240409-2.log」です。
アプリを起動した状態で「log_20240409-2.log」をフォルダ移動できないのは予想がつくので問題ないですが、
アプリ起動直後に作成された「log_20240409-0.log」も移動できません。
（エラーメッセージ「別のプログラムがこのフォルダーまたはファイルを開いているので操作を完了できません」）
プロセスを確認したところ、javaw.exeが握っていました。
ちなみに、log_20240409-1.logはファイル移動できます。
アプリ起動直後に作成されたファイルがオープンされたまま？ということでしょうか...
アプリを起動したまま上記ファイルを移動できるようにする解決策がありましたら、ご教示願います。
